# Why is my android app visible in the multi-task button after crashing

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

My android crashes sometimes because of Out of memory error. While I am trying to fix that, I am seeing that the app is visible when I press the  Multi-task button (after the app crashes). Restarting the app once again at that point crashes the app once again.

Answer (score 1):

Multitask button is basically a recent app button. So no matter how your app was closed or minimised. It'll listed over there.